# Thread Declaration in C++

Tags: c++11, pthreads

I was going through a project code in C. In there, I saw this declaration of thread :

```
pthread_t ui_thread = (pthread_t) 0;
```

I didn't understand the part starting from '=' operator. What is it and how can I code the same declaration in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`(pthread_t) 0` converts the literal integer value 0 to a thread handle `pthread_t`. This assumes that such a conversion is possible, and valid, and that this is a meaningful value (probably expected to be "no thread").

The full statement creates a variable `ui_thread` which is a thread handle of type `pthread_t`, and initializes it with this value.

In C++, you could probably write the same if you were on a platform where it was valid for C. However, you would be better to use the C++ thread library.

```
std::thread t;
```

will create a default-constructed thread handle with no associated thread, which is likely the equivalent to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The `(pthread_t)` part is known as `type casting` in `C`. Also called `explicit type conversion`. It is just a way for the programmer to inform the compiler that the programmer means for the value (`0` in this case) to be treated as the type `pthread_t`.

The code you have is still valid C++.

In C++11 you can probably just do this:

```
pthread_t ui_thread{nullptr};
```